# Customizing the predefined callbacks of Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar buttons

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have GUI based interface where the user can select and unselect different properties to plot on a canvas, which is why it is important for me to use `axis.autoscale_view` every time a new plot is plotted. This seems to work fine until the use decides to zoom in a graph and then hits the home button and plots something new. After which for some reason the `autoscale_view` stops working.

For this reason, I want to embed this directly in the callback function of the home button provided in the navigation toolbar. Is it possible to modify the already created callback function of the home button in the navigation toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon your question ... not sure if it's still relevant, but here's a hacky way how you could do it by decorating the `toolbar._update_view` function ...
(`_update_view` is called whenever the `home` or the `change view` buttons are pressed from the gui toolbar)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5])

def update_decorator(f):
    def newf(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("something happened")        
        return ret
    return newf

# decorate toolbar._update_view 
# (called whenever the home-button or the change-view button is pressed in a gui)
toolbar = f.canvas.toolbar
if toolbar is not None:
    toolbar._update_view = update_decorator(toolbar._update_view)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the thing that I was looking for. I had temporarily found a work around my problem. But this is the better solution and can generally be applied to a lot of applications will help my programming knowledge in the future. Cheers!

Comment: great :-)   care about accepting it as an answer then?